# Android Swipe Open and Load more Click :Causing error 'RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe-gesture

My Application is similar to a gmail inbox. When application opens i am calling a API giving the response of last one months messages,at the scroll end there is a loadmore button, on clicking that button we get full messages, Also a functionality swipe delete in the recyclerview.
The Bug is when i open the swipe and click loadmore button causing this error, the swipe is close, there is no issues.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView'
>   on a null object reference
>           notifications.SwipeHelper$2.onTouch(SwipeHelper.java:53)
>           at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11721)

```
 notificationRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        notificationRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), Models, ListFragment.this);
        notificationRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    SwipeHelper swipeHelper = new SwipeHelper(getActivity() ,notificationRecyclerView) {
                @Override
                public void instantiateUnderlayButton(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, List<UnderlayButton> underlayButtons) {
                    underlayButtons.add(new SwipeHelper.UnderlayButton(
                            "Delete",
                            0,
                            Color.parseColor("#868686"),
                            new SwipeHelper.UnderlayButtonClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(int pos) {


                                }
                            }
                    ));

                }
            };
        }
```

**SwipeHelper.Class**

```
  private View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent e) {
            if (swipedPos < 0) return false;
            Point point = new Point((int) e.getRawX(), (int) e.getRawY());

            RecyclerView.ViewHolder swipedViewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(swipedPos);
            View swipedItem = swipedViewHolder.itemView;
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            swipedItem.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);

            if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                if (rect.top < point.y && rect.bottom > point.y)
                    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
                else {
                    recoverQueue.add(swipedPos);
                    swipedPos = -1;
                    recoverSwipedItem();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Debug this "
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder swipedViewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(swipedPos);"

Comment: is swipedViewHolder is not null ?

Comment: @AbubakkerMoallim getting value 10 in swipedPos

Comment: swipedViewHolder value ?

Comment: @AbubakkerMoallim getting Null

Comment: Yes so your error is here. the method u r using for getting view is not working

Comment: @AbubakkerMoallim then what i do? Can i give this checking  if (swipedViewHolder == null) return false;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171005/discussion-between-abubakker-moallim-and-rose).

Comment: Any Luck on this?

Comment: I resolved it just change swipedPos =-1 as below 
public override bool OnSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e)
            {
                foreach (UnderlayButton button in buttons)
                {
                    if (button.onClick(e.GetX(), e.GetY()))
                    {
                        swipedPos = -1;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }